# Yocto - Add Files to kernel-sources for every kernel version

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, device-tree

I want to add several devicetrees from my hardware projects into my kernel sources, regardless of the kernel version. Currently I'm using pyro with linux-xlnx_2017.1 and I want to switch to rocko the next time.

So i have sevaral *.dts* files in my custom *meta-bsb* layer, which i want to include. I tried to make a recipe *include-hw-dts.bb*, but it doesn't work properly. I'm afraid the patch isn't applied, when running *bitbake virtual/kernel".

So in short: Is there a way to add a bunch of files into my kernel sources, without updating the recipe for each new kernel version / xilinx linux release? I would like to store my .dts files directly in my layer and not using patches if possible.

Comment: You can specify a DTS file in `KERNEL_DEVICETREE` bitbake variable. So maybe try something like KERNEL_DEVICETREE = "mydevicetree.dtb" in local.conf or custom machine configuration.

Comment: I specify my dts/dtb file in my machine conf file, this is working. I just need sometihng which is inserting the dts files into my kernel sources.

Comment: Solution with patch file should work, did you put `FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"` in your linux bbappend file ?

Comment: Yes i did, but i think my recipe isn't called, when i don't specify a kernel version

Comment: you should use <recipe>_%.bbappend to override linux recipes,, you cannot relay on another recipe, unless you make every linux recipes to DEPENDS on your dts recipe.

Comment: Ok thank you! I'll try this sounds nice.